# What is simplest way to repeat a video in a MediaElement

Tags: wpf, video

I have a MediaElement where the source is bound to some data

```
<MediaElement Source='{Binding Something}' />
```

What is the simplest way to have the video repeat? Ideally, MediaElement would have a repeat behavior property.

```
<MediaElement RepeatBehavior='Forever' ... />
```

But I can't find such a property.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add a Storyboard to the MediaElement. See the example below:

```
<MediaElement Name="myMediaElement" >
      <MediaElement.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MediaElement.Loaded">
          <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>

                <!-- The MediaTimeline has a RepeatBehavior="Forever" which makes the media play
                     over and over indefinitely.-->
                <MediaTimeline Source="media\tada.wav" Storyboard.TargetName="myMediaElement"  
                 RepeatBehavior="Forever" />

              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
      </MediaElement.Triggers>
    </MediaElement>
```

Comment: FWIW this method would start to bog down after repeating the video for 1-3 minutes. I think this opens the video file each time through. I used the method from this other answer and it loops forever without slowdowns/freezing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5975876/31307

Comment: @goldenratio yes tested it as well, and after a while it doesn't repeat anymore, and the app gets sluggish, so it is obviously some kind of resource leak

Answer (score 19):

I made it work by setting the [`UnloadedBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.unloadedbehavior%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to [`MediaState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediastate%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).`Manual` and the following code:

```
private void mediaElement_OnMediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mediaElement.Position = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
    mediaElement.Play();
}
```

Setting the position to Zero didnt work...

Comment: I came to this question in-order to answer the very same answer so I must mention that setting the position to `TimeSpan.Zero` works out just fine.

Comment: I tested my self and find that is working fine with TimeSpan.Zero. Nice Ken

Comment: +MasterMastic TimeSpan.Zero not working for all cases.

Comment: This and TimeSpan.Zero worked for me the best.  The trigger was prematurely rewinding the video in the loop and wouldn't play the video to the end.

Comment: Remove `mediaElement.Play();` if you have `LoadedBehaviour` set to `Play`.

Comment: Also works for gif graphics. I hate that there is no easy and reliable way built in.

Comment: `TimeSpan.Zero` created an annoying flicker effect every time the video restarted; setting it to `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10)` (10ms) worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a little late, but I couldn't get to work the example from MSDN. So after research I've found this project: [WPF Media Kit](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit), just click at the Browse link in the Latest Version at the right side of the screen. You'll enter the code of the sample application. I liked this library because a loop was as simple as:

```
MediaUriElement MyPlayer.Loop = True;
```

or
`<DirectShowControls:MediaUriElement x:Name="MyPlayer" Loop="True" />`

Hope this helps someone else.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `mediaElement.Position = new TimeSpan(0,0,1)` to the media player method doesn't (before playing the media) have any effect rather as suggested by MasterMastic and Guido Zanon. I created MediaElement event for MediaEnded with the given content and it worked.