# c# WPF how to repeat MediaElement playback from mediaended event handler without declaring new source?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling, mediaelement

I'm playing a video in WPF.i want it to loop so what I did is when the mediaended event fires, I play back my video. so this will get me a loop. prob is why do u I have to create new source again? why can't I just call 'play'?

I don't want to do it in XAML as for some reason.

have a look at my code snippet:

```
string startPath System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);


public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        media.Source = new Uri(startPath + @"playlist.wpl");
        media.play();
    }

private void Media_Ended(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        media.Source = new Uri(startPath + @"playlist.wpl"); //if i dont put this line, video wont play..seems like it cant get the source
        media.Play();
    }
```

or is there a proper way to loop NOT in XAML but in here .cs file?

Answer (score 21):

Instead of resetting the Source at the start of your Media_Ended handler, try setting the Position value back to the start position.  The Position property is a TimeSpan so you probably want something like...

```
private void Media_Ended(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    media.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
    media.Play();
}
```

Comment: thnx for your answer. i've tried this earlier but no success.video doesnt play back.

Comment: Hmmm...that's strange. I tested it, but with an audio file not a video. Not sure why video would be different - I'll take another look.

Comment: For some reasons this combination doesnot working sometimes! In my case for gif.

Answer (score 12):

You don't even need to set LoadedBehavior as **Manual** just leave it  **Play**.

And reset your media position on MediaEnded.

The new position of the video should be **greater than zero**:

```
private void MediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     media.Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I make it work setting the UnloadedBehavior="Manual" and the follwing code

```
 private void gifAnimation_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    gifAnimation.Position = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
    gifAnimation.Play();
 }
```

Setting the position to Zero didnt work...

Comment: this worked for me! setting to zero did not work. followed instructions here and worked for me. my case was an animated gif.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use this code :

```
private void Media_Ended(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   media.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
   media.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Please don't provide "code only" answers. Why do you think this is the answer?

Comment: This worked for me, you can't call "Play" if the LoadBehaviour has already been set to Play in the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You don't have to set the source again.Just set the position of the mediaelement to the start on the media_ended event</strike>

```
 private void MediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((MediaElement)(sender)).Stop();
            ((MediaElement)(sender)).Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
            ((MediaElement)(sender)).Play();
        }
```

You may need to set MediaElement.LoadedBehavior to Manual

**EDIT**

I have tried loading an asf file with the REPEAT tag and its working fine

```
<ASX version = "3.0">
   <TITLE>Simple ASX Demo</TITLE>
<REPEAT> 
      <ENTRY>
         <TITLE>Vista Butterfly Video</TITLE>
         <AUTHOR>Microsoft Corporation</AUTHOR>
         <COPYRIGHT>(c)2007 Microsoft Corporation</COPYRIGHT>
         <REF HREF = "Butterfly.wmv" />
     </ENTRY>
</REPEAT> 
</ASX>
```

But i think the inbuilt playlist handling mechanism of mediaelement has some flaws.I recommend following the workaround mentioned in the below link

http://blog.revolunet.com/index.php/general/wpf-mediaelement-asx-workaround

Post comment here if you have any problem

Comment: it seems that it's working if the media is a single file but not working if i use a playlist file such as .wpl or .asx file format. any clue?

Comment: So after the entire playlist is finished...you want to repeat from the first file right ?

Comment: Also how do you manage your playlist ? AFIK The MediaElement does not have a built in playlist handling mechanism.

Comment: yeah.i want to play all from the beginning.so i did all the same as your instruction but the media source is a .wpl file. i tried an .asx file but the same result.it doesnt repeat back. if i use media source such as lexus.mp4, everything goes fine using ur instruction..any idea?

Comment: @biju,thnx mate.i'll give it a go and see how.thnx again.