# How to run the MediaPlayer on repeat mode in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `MediaPlayer`

```
public MediaPlayer backgroundMusicPlayer = new MediaPlayer ();
```

Now, because its background music, I'd like to repeat the song after its over.

How should I implement this?

This is what I found:

An event is raised when the song ends: `backgroundMusicPlayer.MediaEnded`

I am not sure what I should do about this? I am new to C# and programming in general.

EDIT:

```
public void PlaybackMusic ( )
{
    if ( backgroundMusicFilePath != null )
    {
         backgroundMusicPlayer.Open (new Uri (backgroundMusicFilePath));
         backgroundMusicPlayer.MediaEnded += new EventHandler (Media_Ended);
         backgroundMusicPlayer.Play ();

         return;
    }
}

private void Media_Ended ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    backgroundMusicPlayer.Open (new Uri (backgroundMusicFilePath));
    backgroundMusicPlayer.Play ();
}
```

This works, but I need to open the file every time. Is this the only way?

Comment: What about [Settings.setMode(autoRewind)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Check with this answer and let us know if it works for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975388/c-sharp-wpf-how-to-repeat-mediaelement-playback-from-mediaended-event-handler-wi

Comment: @Robert - Sorry for being extremely dumb, but how is the Media_Ended function going to be called? I need to set up some mechanism right? This should work

Comment: Okay I got it, but I have to open the source file every time.

Comment: You just have to handle the event, plug-in the song and play it again.

Comment: you just need `backgroundMusicPlayer.Play();` in `backgroundMusicPlayer_MediaEnded`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of resetting the Source at the start of your Media_Ended handler, try setting the Position value back to the start position. The Position property is a TimeSpan so you probably want something like.

```
private void Media_Ended(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    media.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
    media.Play();
}
```

**EDIT 1 :** Find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975388/c-sharp-wpf-how-to-repeat-mediaelement-playback-from-mediaended-event-handler-wi)