# How to loop the sound in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a MediaPlayer like so

`MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.Open(new Uri("Data/bg.mp3", UriKind.Relative));
mp.Play();`

and sound plays once and stops. I tried looking up how to loop it and even found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24320649/8873517) but i can't see why that function would even be called. So I would like to hear any ways to loop it.

Comment: How that event is wired is shown in the question. For you it will be `mp.MediaEnded += new EventHandler (Media_Ended);`

Comment: Did you try the code from the post you linked to?

Comment: @DavidTansey of course I did, didn't work, obviously

Comment: @rene I will try that, thanks

Comment: Yeah, what rene adviced really worked, thanks!