# 'MediaClock.MediaClock(MediaTimeline)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#

I've been trying to loop a soundtrack using this:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Music();

            MediaClock Repeater = new MediaClock(Timeline);

            AudioOutput.Clock = Repeater;

        }
        internal static MediaTimeline Timeline;

        public static void Music()
        {
            double numbers = 999999999999999999;
            RepeatBehavior repeatAlmostInfinitely = new RepeatBehavior(numbers);
            TimeSpan Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 58);
            Duration duration = new Duration(Duration);
            TimeSpan? beginTime = new TimeSpan?();
            MediaTimeline mediatimeline = new MediaTimeline(beginTime, duration, repeatAlmostInfinitely);
            Timeline = mediatimeline;
        }

    }
```

But it says that " 'MediaClock.MediaClock(MediaTimeline)' is inaccessible due to its protection level. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `MediaClock`'s Contructor is protected internal. So you cant instantiate this class. What is `AudioOutput`?

Comment: @lokusking AudioOutput is the MediaElement in the MainWindow.xaml, WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use

```
private void mediaElement_OnMediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mediaElement.Position = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
    mediaElement.Play();
}
```

as someone stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406736/what-is-simplest-way-to-repeat-a-video-in-a-mediaelement)