# Is there any default time interval for mediaended event to be fired?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, media, mediaelement

I have a WPF application which dynamically loads video or image files(depending on user's choice, to a `MediaElement` control.
It is working fine when it is a video and gets the `MediaEnded` event fired on ending the video.
But when I load an image, the `MediaEnded`event is fired within 5 seconds.
Is it a default value? or can I change it programmatically? 
Is there any property to change this interval or disable such an option? 
Is it possible to make it paused until a specific action?

I have set the following properties as follows

```
MediaControl1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
MediaControl1.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MediaElement` is a (very thin) wrapper around Windows Media Player (or rather - uses the same framework which is used by Windows Media Player). If you open an image in Windows Media Player - you will see it will "play" it like a slideshow (even for 1 image), for about 5 seconds. That's why you get `MediaEnded` event in 5 seconds - Windows Media Player plays slideshow with your image for that duration. I doubt there is a way to change this from WPF (because it's behavior of external program\framework, not related to `MediaElement` itself) and I'm not aware of the way to change this for Windows Media Player (and even if there is such a way - it will have global effect and you probably don't want to modify your clients computer in such a way).

To solve your problem - just don't use `MediaElement` for displaying images - use something like `Image` control. If you have really strong reasons to do that - you can pause `MediaElement` with `Pause` method after your "slideshow" has been loaded, then it will not fire `MediaEnded` event. All in all - I cannot imagine any use case where you really have to use `MediaElement` for images.

Comment: Definitely not WMP.  This is all done by MilCore, surely it is wrapping Media Foundation.  I suspect it comes [from this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787399(v=vs.85).aspx) with UseValueForDefault = True and Medium.  But too hard to reverse-engineer.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat the media when you load image. Handle `MediaEnded` event like this:

```
void me_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //play video again
    mediaElement.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    mediaElement.Play();
}
```

Additionally see this. It may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3406857/5675763